# Routing in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to identify categories in my site in url not by id, but by its name. When i'm adding category, which name contains "+" symbol - i have 404 error. This situation is on product internet server, when i'm deploying on local visual studio server - all work fine. Please, suggest me smth.

Example:
    `routes.MapRoute(

      "Default",

      "{controller}/{action}/{id}",

      new { controller = "Home", action = "Catalog", id = "" }

    );`

http://wazy.ru/Catalog/Category/18+

Comment: The "+" symbol is a perfectly valid url character. Is it just these pages that return a 404?

Comment: yes. i think, that my iis server is configured so, because is i wrote on local visual studio category page displayed

Comment: Please can you list the route and the url you're trying to throw at it?

Comment: your PLUS sign in this case probably shouldn't be transformed into a space. This is probably the case. But it should still not throw a 404, unless you do something like that in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Server wont throw 404 error when category names wrong. I think IIS cannot reach-invoke controller or action. Maybe [this link](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) help to figure out how to deploy.